# Theoretical questions about error handling in C99

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, linker-errors, c99

I have two questions regarding error types in C99.

1. is "Two function definitions with identical prototypes detected" considered a compilation error or is it a linking error, I would be happy for an explanation regarding the answer.
2. Can we regard "Size of static variable exceeded maximally allowed bytes" as an error that can occur in all phases (compilation, linking, runtime)?,I managed to get why we can consider it a compilation and runtime error but I still can't manage to comprehend how it can be treated as a linking error.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "prototypes" are irrelevant, it's only the *name* that is used to check for multiple definitions. E.g. `int foo(int X);` and `int foo(float f);` will have different prototypes but the same name so will lead to multiple definition errors.

Comment: These are 2 different matters, you should ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a linking error. Check the following example:

**foo.h**

```
int bar(void);
```

**foo.c**

```
int bar(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int bar(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    return bar();
}
```

You can compile it with '-c' option in gcc, wich means "Compile and assemble, but do not link.". It runs just fine:

```sh
$ gcc -c main.c foo.c
```

However, if you try to link it:

```sh
$ gcc main.c foo.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccFILZyR.o: in function `bar':
foo.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `bar'; /tmp/ccJ1YUOR.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When compiling these source files, you get their respective object files with the function definitions inside. The error will only occur when trying to place those definitions in *main.c*, i.e. linking *foo.o* against *main.o*.

2. I honestly can't imagine an overflow occurring in the linking phase. Could you show an example in which such thing happens?

Comment: Thats the problem, it is an exam question with a final answer only,I. could not possibly think of a way to have a linking problem with it, thank you either way